# Microsoft Word 2010 - Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to a table in Microsoft Word 2010, in much the same way that it is possible in Microsoft Excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know, the old Microsoft Office 96 could do this.

Ah yes, why not just insert an Excel spreadsheet.

Hit the little arrow below Table on the Ribbon and voila! Like it's 1 - 9 - 9 - 6. . .

Comment: Thank you, surfasb - I considered this but was hoping that I would be able to do it directly via Word without embedding an Excel spreadsheet.  However, it does appear that this is the only (simplest) way to go about it.  Thank you anyway for your very amusing response!

Comment: Yeah, I must of spent like two hours on researching a different method to test some software yesterday. Instead I could of just finished those tests in those two hours.  For me, that was a huge failure in cost/benefit analysis.

Comment: I must have missed there was a 96 version of Microsoft office between the 95 and the 97 versions.

Comment: @R.Schreurs not sure if that was sarcasm four years ago, but there was no Office '96, though Office '97 came out in '96. You're welcome.

Comment: @Sam_Butler, it was.  I remember running to the shop to get a box of Office 97. I was a Access/VBA programmer at the time and 32-bit VBA had some great improvements I desperately wanted at the time. Unfortunately at the moment, I can’t remember what they were

Answer (score 4):

Conditional Formatting in Microsoft Word 2010:

Go to "Replace", click in the box next to "Find what" and type in your condition.  (If your condition is more than just words and/or numbers, check in the "Format" or "Special" buttons to see if you can (or need to) more closely identify what you want Word to find.)  Then click in the box next to "Replace with" but don't type anything.  Instead, click on the "Format" button and choose how you want it formatted.  Then of course, click "Replace all".  Please note, this will only work for text already in the document.  All future occurrences will have to be "replaced" again.  Please also remember that Word is designed to work with text and probably won't be as good at identifying mathematical variables as Excel.

I hope this was helpful!  :)

Comment: On Word for Mac go to `Advanced Find and Replace` > `Replace` > click the downward pointing chevron in the bottom left to expand > Click in the `Replace with` field > Click `Format` popup at the bottom > select the formatting you want. Super easy!

Comment: This is an answer about how to Find and Replace formatting in Word. "Conditional Formatting" implies the creation of a style or element which automatically changes style in reaction to another value or object - such as a user entering text into a Content Control. For that reason I don't find this particularly relevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using merge fields, you can do something like this:

```
{ IF { =Sum(above) } <> 100 { = Sum(above) \*Charformat } { = Sum(above) \*Charformat } }
```

And format each field `{}` with the color you want.

Comment: This is interesting, but it seems to work only for cells that are computed from other cells.  Can you adapt it to work on cells that are simply filled in by a user who edits the document?

Comment: I think the only way that could work would be via some macro triggered when you edit the cell.

Answer (score -1):

1- Just copy your table from excel
2- In word: Home->Paste options->Link & Keep Source Formatting

Comment: That answer is low quality, as it does not explain anything nor show a source.