# Formatting rules in Word 2010 to style a certain phrase or word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I was hoping/looking for a feature similar to the conditional formatting available in Excel. The particular rule I'm trying to create:

```
Find text "My Spiffy Product 3.0", and format it:
- Bold; and
- Smallcaps
```

**Is there a Word 2010 feature that allows me to format bits of text in my document automatically?**

Some additional thoughts:

- There's a [related question on conditional table formatting](https://superuser.com/q/355088/82470), but this is not about tables but pieces of text.
- I'm looking for a feature that's (close to) "always on", so Search & Replace on itself doesn't cut it.
- My case is Word 2010, but it would be nice to know if solutions/answers are available in 2007 as well.
- I'm not too fussed about the available formatting options (bold, color, etc), anything that makes the text stand out a bit more is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the AutoCorrect feature of MS Word to do this. Use the following steps:

1. **Type** your text "Spiffy Product 3.0"
2. **Format** your text the way you want it to be
3. **Highlight** the text
4. Go to Options -> Proofing -> **AutoCorrect**
5. In the AutoCorrect dialog box, type the **phrase you want replaced** "My Spiffy Product 3.0" (or feel free to shorten to SP3, or something similary quick to type)
6. Make sure the "**With Formatted Text**" radio button is selected.
7. Click okay to accept the changes.

From now on, whenever you type the text you entered, it will automatically convert to your formatted text.  And, when you upgrade to Spiffy Product 4.0, it's easy to add this to AutoCorrect as well.

Also, if you have documents that aren't already properly formatted yet, you can use the find/replace function with similar formatted text option to pick up old entries.

Comment: Thanks @DavidVandenbos, this worked for me. It's a shame it won't pick up on text that's copy-pasted into the document, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not as computer savvy as I'd like to be, but I was clicking around because I had the same concern, and I also found a way if it helps.

I was looking for a way to highlight a certain word I was using over and over again.

I used the find function by pressing CTRL + F to find my key word
I typed in the key word in the search bar
That word was then highlighted throughout my paper
So then I noticed on the side of the search bar, there was the X button and then a small drop down arrow
I clicked the small drop down arrow and scrolled down to "replace"
From there you can type in a key word or phrase and depending on what you'd like
(bold, italics, etc) you can adjust your settings there
I selected CTRL + B for bold because that's what I wanted done with my paper

I'm not sure if that helped at all, just I'd pass that along to anyone with a similar situation :o)

Comment: Ah, yes, I remember my question from a few years back. For me, then, the Search & Replace method (as I called it in the question) wasn't good enough because I didn't want to have to remember to do that every time I updated the document. But it might help others nonetheless.

Comment: Haha yeah this is my first time ever commenting in a forum :/ after I sent my response, I looked at your original question and happened to see the year it was posted was like 2012 or something haha wow! But glad you found that solution years ago! Lol and thank you!