# Is it possible to use conditional formatting in Word 365?

Tags: microsoft-word, conditional-formatting, office365

Is it possible to use conditional formatting in Word 365, as it is possible to do in Excel 365?

I know that you can add an Excel sheet inside a Windows document, and use conditional formatting inside this Excel sheet. But I wondered whether there is a more direct/elegant way to do it in Windows. (I think that it is not the case.)

(See [Microsoft Word 2010 - Conditional Formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/355088/microsoft-word-2010-conditional-formatting) for Word 2010.)

Comment: Word 365 or Excel 365 is not a product, but a way to license the software. Depending on your 365 license, you can download Word and/or Excel as desktop versions on your machine and you can use the features available to your license. Have you tried the steps outlined in the link you posted with desktop versions of Word and Excel with your license? If not, please do. If you have, please share what the problem is, if there is any.